# Does VS Code Server Support PAM based authentication

Tags: visual-studio-code, pam, sssd, code-server

I am setting up the Code Server. I have already setup other webapps such as RStudio, Jupiter Notebook to get authenticated against Active Directory using PAM + SSSD configuration.

I want Code Server webapp to also get authenticated and setup using PAM +SSSD.

I did not find any documentation related to that. Is there a way to configure it. If not what are the alternatives.